# apply making conversion (POSIXct)

Tags: r, type-conversion, apply

I was using apply on a data.frame with POSIXct objects. 
The problem is that apply begins with converting the input data.frame as.matrix() (according to [what I read](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-January/151172.html)). Which means that POSIXct will then be casted to char.

I solve my issue by using lapply instead. However is there some better solutions?

```
    # data.frame with one column of posixct
    pos = data.frame(dateTime = c(Sys.time(), Sys.time(), Sys.time()))
    str(pos) # POSIXct

    test = function(x){
      str(x[1])
      return(x)
    }                 
    res = data.frame(apply(pos, 2, test))
    str(res) # all strings

    res2 = data.frame(lapply(pos, test))
    str(res2) # all POSIXct
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `map_df` function from the `purrr` package. The `map` function has different versions for different output types so for this case you would use `map_df`

```
# data.frame with one column of posixct
pos = data.frame(dateTime = c(Sys.time(), Sys.time(), Sys.time()))
str(pos) # POSIXct

test = function(x){
  str(x[1])
  return(x)
}                 
res = data.frame(apply(pos, 2, test))
str(res) # all strings

res2 = data.frame(lapply(pos, test))
str(res2) # all POSIXct

library(purrr)

res3 = map_df(pos, test)
str(res3)
```